# Previous activity stays on activity stack

Tags: android, stack

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro) which is a Wizard.
When user is done with the Wizard and clicks Done button he moves to another Activity.
I have added to Manifest file `android:noHistory="true"` for the WizardActivity and also when I start  the next activity im doing it like this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProjectsActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Nevertheless when user click backs he still goes to the WizardActivity. I'd like the user either to exit or go the activity that started the WizardActivity.

Thank you

Comment: I did not understand , would you want the "guide screen" is performed one time?
Or that in onBackPressed is not carried out ?

Comment: can you please add your manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` the activity after launching the other Activity. i.e after `startActivity(intent)` add `finish()`

Comment: what is the problem you are facing.?